# Why does my object keep rotating even though I tell it to stop at 90 degrees

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I wrote this code where I tell an object that it should keep rotating until it hits 90 degrees, but it keeps on rotating. Anyway here's the code:

```
public class playerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float transformZ;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        transformZ = 0;
        transform.position = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, transformZ);
        while (transformZ != 90)
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, 0, transformZ);
            transformZ = transformZ + 0.1f;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        }

        
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but where should I write this code and how should I use it?

Comment: Now it says " 'Mathf' does not contain a definition for 'ApproximatelyEqual'".

Comment: Thanks, but now it gives me this error "Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'float'"

Comment: Either `while(transformZ < 90)` or `while(!Mathf.Approximately(transformZ, 90)`.

Comment: Thanks, the error is now gone, but the problem which I had in the beginning still remains. But I noticed that transformZ doesn't count the rotation around the Z-axis, but it counts the time passed until it hits 90 seconds, why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TransformZ is Being Set Wrong

In your function, you are increasing transformZ by itself + `0.1` every `0.1f` seconds. Instead of this you should just directly use`transform.eulerAngles.z` as that provides the exact rotation and you don't need to keep a variable that you increment.

### Checking for Exact Inequality

You should not be checking exactly for whether transformZ is not equal to 90, considering this is a float value we are dealing with. There should either be  a threshold:

```cs
while(Mathf.Abs(90f - transform.eulerAngles.z) < [THRESHOLD])
```

or you could simply just have the while loop check if its below 90 as [Aybe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361899/aybe) pointed out.

```
while(transform.eulerAngles.z < 90)
```

Comment: In general careful though with [eulerAngles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html)! Instead I would rather keep track of the value you actually rotated and check if that exceeds the 90. In general are we sure OP wants to rotate exponentially via `Rotate(0, 0, transformZ) ` where `tranaformZ` is getting bigger with each iteration?

Comment: Yes, I said that the code worked (which it did, it turned 90°) because I wasn't home and so couldn't check it, but the problem that I have is that it turns 90° instantly but I want it to happen over a certain amount of time. How can I do that?

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind, I used your code below and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I see various issues here

- you increase `transformZ` by `0.1` every `0.1` seconds => this will count seconds, not the actually applied rotation (see further below)
- you rotate about a value `transformZ` that is getting bigger each time. Have in mind that `Rotate` does **not set** a final rotation but rather starts add the current rotation and **adds** to it.

  You are rotating like

  ```
   Iteration | current rotation | transformZ | resulting rotation

           1 | 0                +          0 = 0
           2 | 0                +        0.1 = 0.1
           3 | 0.1              +        0.2 = 0.3
           4 | 0.3              +        0.3 = 0.6
           5 | 0.6              +        0.4 = 1.0
          ...
  ```
- then also in general [never use `==` / `! =` for floating point values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)
- using `Rotate` there is always the possibility that you overshoot the target rotation
- and then personally I would prefer a continuous rotation instead of `0.1` second jumps.

---

A solution depends a bit on what you want to control.

For a fixed rotation per second I would do

```
[SerializeField] private float anglePerSecond;
[SerializeField] private float maxAngle = 90;

IEnumerator Start() 
{
    ... 

    var initialRotation = transform.rotation;
    // precalculate the desired rotation going through Quaternion instead of directly Euler space 
    var targetRotation = initialRotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, maxAngle);

    // here "Quaternion != Quaternion] uses a lower precise check that allows for small rounding errors
    while (transform.rotation != targetRotation)
    {
        // with linear anglePerSecond rotate towards the final rotation
        // Without ever overshooting the target rotation
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, anglePerSecond * Time.deltaTime);
        yield return null;
    }

    // to be sure apply final rotation
    transform.rotation = targetRotation;
}
```

Or if you rather want to control the duration in seconds

```
[SerializeField] private float durationInSeconds = 1f;
[SerializeField] private float maxAngle = 90;

IEnumerator Start() 
{
    ... 

    var initialRotation = transform.rotation;
    var targetRotation = initialRotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, maxAngle);

    // similar as before but this time iterate over a certain time
    for(var timePassed = 0f; timePassed < durationInSeconds; timePassed += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        // factor linear growing from 0 to 1
        var factor = timePassed / durationInSeconds;
        // advantage: you can add ease in/out quote easily e.g.
        //factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, factor);
        // interpolate via given factor
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(initialRotation, targetRotation, factor);
        yield return null;
    }

    transform.rotation = targetRotation;
}
```